# Qt5 directshow plugin (dsengine.dll) is not built under Windows7

Tags: qt, directshow, qt5

I’ve tried to build the directshow multimedia plugin in Qt5 under Windows7, however, there is a problem that qedit.h is not found, as this file was removed from WindowsSDK 7.1 (which is the one I am required to use to build Qt5).
So I tried to follow this [post here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/2ab5c212-5824-419d-b5d9-7f5db82f57cd).
Just adding this qedit.h (from what I see it just needs the IID_ISampleGrabber and CLSID_SampleGrabber and that’s it) and recompiling. It linked alright, but when I run my application, if I try to play video it just doesn’t do a damn thing, and if I try to access the camera it just quits the application right away. Since I have no idea about the inner workings of DS, I don’t know how legitimate this fix is.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.